# I keep getting the following error. Notice: Undefined index: asset_tag in

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE inventory1.asset_details SET status='". 
$_POST['status']."', To='" . $_POST['location_name']."', notes='". 
$_POST['notes']."' WHERE asset_tag=" . $_POST['asset_tag']);
```

Comment: Post your HTML from your form

Comment: By the way, your site is WIDE open to SQL injection...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `'asset_tag'` does not appear as a key in your `$_POST[]` array.  You should check your HTTP request to make sure the value is getting passed in.

Comment: Okay, thank you peter. I am not sure how i would fix this this problem I am new to php and mysql

Comment: you either need an input named 'asset_tag' in your html form or you need to add it to your post array before building your query.

Comment: The problem is in the request comming in.  Your client is sending you information that does not include `'asset_tag'`. IF that is not a required field you should test for its existence (for example using `array_key_exists()`) and then conditionally add it to your SQL statement when it is present.  Otherwise you are generating a syntactically incorrect SQL command.